# How should I handle an "incorrectly" named dll?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, msys

I am trying to compiling an autodiff python library, pyadolc, on Windows with Mingw. It requires boost python to call the underlying c++ library, adol-c.

I first compiled boost_python library (dll) with mingw. The dll generated are namead as libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll and libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll.a, sitting in /mingw/bin and /mingw/lib respectively.

Then when I build the pyadolc, the build script tries with command -lboost_python. It failed because the dll is named as libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll, not libboost_python.dll.

So I renamed the dll as libboost_python.dll in /mingw/bin. It works and everything links fine.

However, when I tred in python shell

import adolc

it gave me an error: ImportError: No dll found for _adolc (something like that). Then I found that it was because it was looking for libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll.

My question is: how does the dll naming work? what's the proper way to handle this kind of situation? Should I modify the build script or should I just rename the dll? I know in linux, I probably can just create a symbolic link of libboost_python.so to libboost_python-xxxx-mt-1_53.so. But in Windows xp, symbolic link to a file is not that easy.

Comment: Boost's library naming is defined here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming

Answer (score 0):

The information about how dlls are named and found is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ; if you are using Windows Vista or later, you can make symlinks, and for older versions, you can use junction from sysinternals.com

Answer (score 0):

The best possibility is to change your build script to point to `-lboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll`

If you rename  `libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll` you have to rename `libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll.a` to.

Often have `dll's` a reciprocal reference, if you now, only renames, the original names are not found.

So do not `rename`, instead use `copy`

copy

`libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll.a` to `libboost_python.a`

and copy

`libboost_python-mgw46-mt-1_53.dll` to `libboost_python.dll`

With this method you have both versions.